# Add lines of a multiline textbox into a string / array VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I should replace txtstringnump1 up to 20 textboxes, it creates a list where it is a can write the values ​​until there is still a textbox. how do i do this?

```
 Dim AllNumbers1 As New List(Of IEnumerable(Of ArrayList))
        Dim str As String
        'Set your string value
        For i As Integer = 0 To Globals.TBIntDrawsXCount - 1
            str = TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines(i)
            'Define  new string array containing elements of str divided by space..
            Dim strWords As String() = str.Split(",")
            Dim myArr As Integer() = strWords(0).ToString
     TxtStringNumP1.Text &= strWords(0) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP2.Text &= strWords(1) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP3.Text &= strWords(2) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP4.Text &= strWords(3) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP5.Text &= strWords(4) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP6.Text &= strWords(5) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP7.Text &= strWords(6) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP8.Text &= strWords(7) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP9.Text &= strWords(8) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP10.Text &= strWords(9) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP11.Text &= strWords(10) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP12.Text &= strWords(11) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP13.Text &= strWords(12) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP14.Text &= strWords(13) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP15.Text &= strWords(14) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP16.Text &= strWords(15) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP17.Text &= strWords(16) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP18.Text &= strWords(17) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP19.Text &= strWords(18) & Environment.NewLine
            TxtStringNumP20.Text &= strWords(19) & Environment.NewLine
        Next
```

Comment: write values in a list of string, not in a textboxes.

Comment: This line has all kinds of wrong, and indicates you maybe need to spend more time understanding basic data types before writing any more code: `Dim myArr As Integer() = strWords(0).ToString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code adds lines to succeeding textboxes. When the last textbox is reached, it starts over with the first one:

```
Dim tbIndex As Integer = 0

Dim lines As String() = TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines
For i As Integer = 0 To Globals.TBIntDrawsXCount - 1
    Dim str = lines(i)
    Dim strWords As String() = str.Split(","c)
    For Each word As String In strWords
        Dim tb = DirectCast(Controls.Item("TxtStringNumP" & (tbIndex + 1)), TextBox)
        tb.Text &= word & Environment.NewLine
        tbIndex = (tbIndex + 1) Mod 20
    Next
Next
```

I'm using two tricks:

1. I look up the textbox by name in the Form's `Controls` collection.
2. I use a modulo opertation to limit the index in the range 0 .. 19

I'm not sure if this is what you need. If you need something else, please provide a better description.

---

Note: updated according to @jmcilhinney's suggestion. The lines array is stored before the loop to avoid creating a new array by the TextBox each time.

This code assumes that the required number of lines is available. The line `Dim str = lines(i)` will generate an index-out-of-bounds exception if the TextBox does not contain enough lines. The code would be more robust with an appropriate check.

Comment: There is an issue with that code. It will work but it is not optimal. The `Lines` does not expose "live" data, i.e. there is no array stored internally that the property returns or replaces. That means that a new array object has to be created every time you get the property value. You're doing that in a loop so you're creating multiple arrays for no good reason. You should get the property once and assign the array to a variable, then use that multiple times. If you make changes to the array, you assign it back to the property once when you're done.

Comment: Yes. An even better solution would be to work with data bound forms and controls.

Answer (score 1):

The `Lines` property of the `TextBox` IS an array of the lines. You should have seen that for yourself when you read the documentation for the `TextBox` class, which you should have done before posting here.